# Nstimer Countdown Skip Button

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm using nstimer to run code that changes text every 60 seconds.
I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to skip an iteration of the 60 seconds. Say a user doesn't want to read the text currently on display, at the moment they still have to wait 60 seconds.
Is there a way to immediately move on to the next 60 second loop at a button tap?

This is what I have so far:

```
var array : String[]()

var x = 0


@IBAction func playBtnPressed(sender: UIButton) 
{
    update()

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60, target: self, selector: #selector(PlayVC.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func update()
{
    if x < array.count {

        let item = array[x]

        aLbl.text = array.itemTitle

        x += 1
    }

}

@IBAction func skipBtnPressed(sender: UIButton)
{

}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can give me! :)

Comment: Do you mean that you want `x` incremented by 1 if the user taps the "skip" button? Or just call `update` from your button handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your skipBtnPressed() you should first invalidate the timer, update data and then set another timer. Like this

```
@IBAction func skipBtnPressed(sender: UIButton)
{
    timer.invalidate()
    update()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60, target: self, selector: #selector(PlayVC.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I still have a long way to go lol! Thank you for your help.